# Visual Studio 2013 - No web template

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to begin learning MVC, but when i run visual studio ultimate 2013 there is no web template listed under c# that I can see to click on.

[image: problem]

It should be listed above Office/Sharepoint in all the examples that I have seen, but I can't find a way to make it appear.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you forgot to install Web Developer tool. Are you sure that you have done full install ?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2013 has no distinct project types for different ASP.Net features.

Please select .NET Framework 4.5 (or higher) in order to see the ASP.NET Web Application template (For ASP.NET One).
Select Visual C# -> Web ->ASP.NET Web Application, under that select the "MVC checkbox in the next step".

Comment: I'm still slightly confused. In the picture you can see that I have .net framework 4.5 selected, and I can't see any web application template. Because of that I can't do the second step you say. Am I missing something obvious here?

Also, I do actually have no problem getting this to work with the web express edition, this is just with the 2013 ultimate edition I am having this problem.